# Android background color set to gray instead of @android:color/white

Tags: android, layout, colors, background

In my app all the views whose background is set to `@background="@android:color/white"` are showed properly on all the devices apart from Samsung Galaxy S3 mini. In this case all these views have a gray background set.

[image]

In this specific case the background of the LinearLayout containing the checkboxes should be white:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_child1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
...
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to replace `android:background="@android:color/white"` with `android:background="#FFFFFF"`, but the only working solution has be the one of creating a white_bg.xml into my drawable directory:

```
<item android:bottom="0px">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

and changing the background setting to `android:background="@drawable/white_bg"`.

Thought this solves my problem, changing all the layouts in my app is quite annoying, especially because this problem seems to affect in few devices only. I wonder if there's a more elegant solution to this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the "windowBackground" in AppTheme:

In "styles.xml"

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

And remove background attribute from your LinearLayout.

Of course make sure your activity using AppTheme as it's theme.
(also set @color/white value to "#ffffffff")

Comment: Maybe in that phone "windowBackground" is defined as gray in the system-theme and for sure in other phones defined as white. You're welcome!